# Cropping animation with imagick results in blue background

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have compiled `ImageMagick 6.8.7-10 Q8 x86_64` on `Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit`.
I also installed `imagick 3.2.0RC1` for `PHP 5.5.7`.

I am using the following to crop an animated gif:

```
$imagick = new \Imagick('anim2.gif');

$imagick = $imagick->coalesceImages();

foreach ($imagick as $frame) {
    $frame->cropImage(80, 80, 0, 0);
    $frame->thumbnailImage(80, 80);
    $frame->setImagePage(80, 80, 0, 0);
}

$imagick = $imagick->deconstructImages();

$imagick->writeImages('test.gif', true);
```

This is the original image: [image]

And the cropped image becomes: [image]

Notice that the cropped image gains a blue background in the second frame.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that coalesce introduces the background. This may or may not be a bug in imagemagick.

If running from the command line, you need to set the background to none before coalescing:

```
convert anim2.gif -background none -coalesce temporary.gif
```

From PHP's imagick library, you need to set all the frames' backgrounds to none:

```
$imagick = new \Imagick('anim2.gif');

foreach ($imagick as $frame) {
   $frame->setImageBackgroundColor('none'); //This is important!
}

$imagick = $imagick->coalesceImages();

foreach ($imagick as $frame) {
    $frame->cropImage(80, 80, 0, 0);
    $frame->thumbnailImage(80, 80);
    $frame->setImagePage(80, 80, 0, 0);
}

$imagick = $imagick->deconstructImages();

$imagick->writeImages('test.gif', true);
```

The result:
[image]